# How to stop clone()?

Tags: jquery

I can't find on the internet a answer for this. I have a `var` that clones a element. This `var` is passed on a `setInterval` function that repeats this procces of cloning every 1 sec. Next, I attempt to stop this procces by one click on document.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7mcno43m/

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    var clone = $('div').clone().first().appendTo('body')
}, 1000);

$(document).click(function(){
    clone = false 
})
```

I know i can do this by using `clearInterval` but I want to find another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set a boolean flag variable which the clone is then based on. `clone` should also be set within scope of both blocks of code for it to be accessible. Try this:

```
var allowClone = true;
var clone;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if (allowClone)
       clone = $('div').clone().first().appendTo('body');
}, 1000);

$(document).click(function(){
    clone = null; // empty it if it was set (optional)
    allowClone = false;
})
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7mcno43m/1/)

I would suggest you use `clearInterval()` instead though, otherwise you're just wasting time and slowing performance.

Comment: This acctualy works. Thank you for the solution and advice :D